# Где хранится / как отредактировать связь между .xib и соответствующим ему классом?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть класс:

```
class XXXTableViewCell_SomeSuffix: UITableViewCell {
```

В Xcode через `Refactor -> Rename` меняю название класса на XXXTableViewCell. Меняются все вхождения класса в коде проекта, но у соответсвующего ячейки .xib остается старое имя, содержащее _SomeSuffix.

Если в панели навигатора отредактировать имя xib-файла вручную, чтобы оно имело такое же имя как у класса `(XXXTableViewCell_SomeSuffix.xib -> XXXTableViewCell.xib)`, то при запуске проекта (Project Clean сделан) будет ошибка:

> Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)'
>   with name 'XXXTableViewCell_SomeSuffix'

Где хранится связь между .xib и соответствующим ему классом? Каким образом  переименовать и xib-файл тоже?

Comment: xib и storyboard файлы вручную очень не рекомендуется редактировать - просто поломаете их. Любое редактирование делается только через InterfaceBuilder. В вашем случае нужно сменить тип класса для вашего объекта. Возможно также сменить еще в File's Owner. 
Имя класса указывается в панели настройки справа - 3я вкладка.
Имя .xib файла можно менять сколько угодно, но помни - когда ты его загружаешь, указываешь именно имя файла без расширения.

Comment: класс у XXXTableViewCell_SomeSuffix.xib стоит верный. Весь затык в том, что сейчас у меня есть ксиб XXXTableViewCell_SomeSuffix.xib и класс XXXTableViewCell.xib. И как переименовать ксиб, так чтобы его имя соответстовало имени класса, непонятно - потому что возникает runtime ошибка (собирается нормально). Так что мне не тип класса у xib нужно поменять

Comment: Покажите как Вы загружаете его. А желательно проектик только с этой частью, где воспроизводится ощибка

Answer (score 0):

[image: identity inspector]

В этом поле назначается выполняющий класс для xib и любых вью в сториборде